# Installing a windows service on another machine

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have been building a windows application. this application contains a windows service which performs certain action when the service is started, for example some FileIO operation.
Now this application needs to be deployed on the server. The server, obviously won't have visual studio in it. So how can i install that windows service there along with the application.
NOTE :- application is installed, just need to know how can i install the windows service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you setup the service correctly you just run installutil.exe /your exe/ .... but you googled that right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on setup the service correctly please. @BugFinder

Comment: but that installs the service like you asked - what specifically then are you having problems with?

Comment: See, in local how do we test a windows service? we creae it using VS2012 command prompt and then use InstallUtil. So, my question is is that how do we install the same on the server?because server wont have VisualStudio in it. @BugFinder

Comment: How you test it is subjective, me, I made a command line option to stop it being a service and running just as a command line - you never mentioned testing it - which normally of course you do on your local machine.. I wont post on this question further - its not clear.